# Trouble with this sentence

Tags: translation

一番好きな人どうしが一番好きでいられる関係が一番だって、信じてるから

My translation would be something like this: Because I believe the best thing is for the person you like best to be liked the best.

I'm having trouble to understand this sentence because the word best keeps being repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「一番好{いちばんす}きな人どうしが一番好きでいられる関係{かんけい}が一番だって、信{しん}じてるから。」

First, let us look at the over-all sentence structure.  It is saying that a certain kind of relationship (関係) is the best.  Now, what kind is that?

It is one in which 「一番好きな人どうし」 can maintain a 「一番好きでいられる」 type of situation.  Are you following?

「一番好きな人どうし」 means "***two*** people who truly love each other (the best)"

「一番好きでいられる」 means "could keep loving each other the best"

Put it altogether and you will have:

> "I believe that it would be the best (kind of) relationship if two people loving each other the best could maintain that relationship."

More literally,

> "I believe that a relationship in which two people who love each other the best could keep loving each other the best would be the best (kind of) relationship."

Wordy, I know, but that is how the original is.

Comment: One question. Loving each other the best sounds a bit weird. I think it would be better translated: 2 people who love each other the most. Do you agree?